# Factors being changed to numeric when I don't want them to be, when moving data from one dataframe to another

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, with-statement

I have a dataframe which contains both numeric variables and factors.

When moving data from one dataframe to another, everything is kept as I would like it:

```
copy_data<-as.data.frame(original_data)
```

This creates a copy of 'original_data' with factors remaining factors.

When I try a more complex version, the end result is a dataframe of numeric values, when I want the factors to still be factors:

```
model_data<-with(subset(copy_data, copy_data$var1<0), 
as.data.frame(cbind(var1, var2, var3, factor1, factor2, factor3)))
```

So factor1, factor2, and factor3 all end up numeric rather than factors. What am I missing? I've tried with and without `as.data.frame` and defining model_data as a dataframe before populating it.

My searches of the StackExchange archive return mostly results about deliberately changing factors to variables, and haven't help me much. The slightly clunky title isto differentiate my question from those.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Perhaps if you made a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your question / problem, people would find it easier to answer. A reproducible example in your case will contain some sample data that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?cbind` says that `cbind` returns a matrix if all the inputs are vectors (which they are in your case).  A a matrix can can only contain a single *atomic* type (character, numeric, logical, etc.).  Factors are not an atomic type, so they get converted.

The "Data frame methods" section says that `cbind` data.frame method just wraps `data.frame(..., check.names=FALSE)`, so you could just call `data.frame` directly (the call to `cbind` is redundant).

```
model_data <- with(subset(copy_data, copy_data$var1<0), 
  data.frame(var1, var2, var3, factor1, factor2, factor3))
```

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly - I had assumed the `cbind` was necessary after reading the `as.data.frame` documentation and hadn't thought to try with out, only to try `c` which obviously doesn't work.